# include() got an unexpected keyword argument 'template_name'

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

Downloaded bootstrap template for tried to test on my project .Got the bootstrap from http://www.pythondiary.com/templates/bootstrap but on running the server the above error occurs

This is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='base.html')),
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

)
```

My settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '$b@svqpv1qwblg#$yds1_b#i*f9e44!pnswns0iu#79&iru9i%'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls',
    'blog',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'bootstrap'),
)
```

help newbie here

Here is the traceback

```
    Environment:


    Request Method: GET
    Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

    Django Version: 1.6.1
    Python Version: 2.7.6
    Installed Applications:
    ('django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'polls',
     'blog')
    Installed Middleware:
    ('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


    Traceback:
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
      99.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
      337.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
      365.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
      360.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
      40.         __import__(name)
    File "/home/sourcerer/PycharmProjects/mysite/mysite/urls.py" in 
      10.     url(r'^$', include(template_name='base.html')),

    Exception Type: TypeError at /
    Exception Value: include() got an unexpected keyword argument 'template_name'
```

Comment: Can you show the traceback?

Comment: Based on the date in `base.html`, this looks like it is from 2012. What versions of Python and Django are you using? Maybe take a look at how TemplateView is used in the current docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview

Comment: using django v 1.6.1 python 2.7 is it compatible with django v 1.8.x ??

Comment: Your traceback's last line and your `mysite/urls.py` line 10 are different. Please check.

Comment: I'm currently using Python 2.7.9 with Django==1.8.2

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments:

> Your traceback's last line and your `mysite/urls.py` line 10 are different.

It is likely that you have not saved the latest version of your `mysite/urls.py` file.

You can also check what `.pyc` files you have lying around by doing `find . -name "*.pyc" -print` and remove all of those files by doing `find . -name "*.pyc" -delete`.